# Not getting the Tag's nodeValue using DOMDocument class in PHP?

Tags: php, dom

i am using DOMDocument class, to parse HTML document in PHP.
     the code of table i am using...

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> 123 employees </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> $50,000 </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

i am not able to fetch nodeValue of the  tag, which are like in the above format,
i.e ($50,000, 123 employees ).

Comment: Try echoing the element itself: `echo (string)$element;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use XPath queries. For example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(...your html...);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//table/tr/td';

$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry)
    print_r($entry->nodeValue); (*)
```

Just replace the line marked with (*) with code that suites your needs.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what you are doing wrong if you don't say, what you are doing at all.

But in principle you must get a reference to the table (as a [DOM element](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)), then get the rows and cells ([child nodes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes)) and get the [node value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue) from there.

If your table is the only one in the document, you'll get it via `$doc->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(0)` (with `$doc` being the [DOM document object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)).